# Would it be possible to "recycle" nuclear warheads into nuclear energy?

Tags: nuclear-physics, nuclear-engineering

The number of nuclear warheads in the world is *estimated* (!) to be over 16,000. [0] Surely, this stockpile represents a massive threat to humanity. My question is simple. Can we repurpose these warheads into a source of energy? I'm imagining some sort of giant hole we can throw nuclear bombs into, and get energy from in exchange.

I know almost nothing about physics.

[0] http://www.ploughshares.org/world-nuclear-stockpile-report

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MOX_fuel

Comment: The world isn't powered by nuclear energy because (1) people are ignorantly afraid of the safest power source known to humanity, and (2) it's not overwhelmingly price competitive to operate nuclear plants as opposed to other plants. The availability of fuel has little to do with the politics and economics of the situation, especially since there's plenty of fuel that doesn't come from nation-states voluntarily surrendering their military investment.

Comment: The general answer is yes, but it's economically not feasible (and it wouldn't add much of anything to the world's energy budget). Given the abundance of safe and cheap renewable energy nuclear reactors are not a good way of generating electricity, let alone any other form of technically useful energy.

Comment: The amount of nuclear weapon fissile material in stock is enough to make close to 100,000 weapons

Answer (score 4):

Not only is it possible, it's been going on for decades.

As part of a 20 year agreement which came to be known as the 'megatons to megawatts' program, the former-USSR decommissioned some 20,000 nuclear warheads from its military arsenal and recovered 500 tonnes of highly enriched uranium which was combined with 15,000 tonnes of low enriched uranium and sold to to the USA where it generated something like [10% of the electricity from 1993 to 2013](http://blogs.discovermagazine.com/d-brief/2013/12/11/russias-decommissioned-nuclear-bombs-provide-10-of-u-s-electricity).